# Compiling Bootstrap from LESS, missing rules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm compiling Bootstrap from the latest LESS files so I can override/add my own variables (mostly colours).

However the compiled css file doesn't contain any of the .span3, .span8 rules, does anyone know how/where these rules are generated?

Downloading the latest pre-compiled css files works fine - these contain the above rules.
I've tried a search on the LESS files, but only the table rules were found (.tableColumns(3), .tableColumns(8) etc..).

My current bootstrap.less looks like:

```
@import "@{BootStrapVer}/variables.less";
@import "@{Custom}/custom-vars.less";
@import "@{BootStrapVer}/mixins.less";

<Rest of bootstrap less files excluded for brevity>
```

Comment: everything is right here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less

Comment: @ScottSimpson - I've downloaded the LESS files from github and my bootstrap.less references them all, but once compiled my bootstrap.css is smaller than the pre-compiled one

Comment: Your bootstrap.less looks exactly like this? https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less Maybe it is how you are compiling. If you are on Mac, try CodeKit for compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought the issue was to do with adding in my custom less files.

Thanks to David Taiaroa's reply and some more debugging, a new version of Prepos and comparing to the output of WinLESS, I eventually determined that it's the settings I was using in [Prepos](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/).

Unselecting "Strict Maths" and "Strict Units" and re-compiling produced the correct CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly, you are wanting a single, standalone CSS file which includes both the Bootstrap defaults plus your customisation.

Start by getting a copy of the less files from https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/archive/master.zip

If you open boostrap.less you will see that towards the top there is

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "mixins.less";
....
```

add a statement calling your custom variable file in the middle of this block, being sure to get the relative path correct.  Eg

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc  
@import "../../relative/path-to/custom-vars.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

Then compile bootsrap.less.

I agree with @ScottSimpson, CodeKit is a good Mac option.

good luck!

Comment: My custom bootstrap.less file is outside my less directory, I've included an example of what I've got. Wouldn't my custom variables need to be imported before I imported the other less files in order to ripple through?

Comment: Even if I try: @import "@{BootStrapVer}/bootstrap.less"; my css file is oddly 3KB smaller then the pre-compiled one.